# Doctrine/Symfony - Inheritance - Relations

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, orm, entity-relationship

I've two entities: Individu (Individual) and Epoux_se (Husband)
Husband extends Individual

```
class Individu
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Individu", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pere_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $pere;

public function __construct($nom, $prenoms, $sexe)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;
    $this->prenoms= $prenoms;
    $this->sexe = $sexe;
    $this->actes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

And the class Husband

```
class Epoux_se extends Individu
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

public function __construct($nom, $prenoms, $sexe, $lieuOrigine, $dateNaissance, $age)
{
    parent::__construct($nom, $prenoms, $sexe);
    $this->lieuOrigine = $lieuOrigine;
    $this->dateNaissance = $dateNaissance;
    $this->age = $age;
}
```

When I import DataFixtures

> new Epoux_se("Aurel", ["Jean-Christophe", "Marc"], "M", "Saint-Malo",
>   "05/08/1722", 22);

I've an error for constructor of Husband

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pere_id' in
>   'field list'
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO epoux_se (nom, prenoms, sexe, profession, pere_id, mere_id, lieu
>   Origine, dateNaissance, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Aurel", "a:2:{i:0;s:15:\"Jean-Christ
>   ophe\";i:1;s:4:\"Marc\";}", "M", null, null, null, "Saint-Malo", "05/08/1722", 22]:

Fixtures:

```
$marie = new Individu("Duhamel", ["Ophelia", "Carmène"], "F"); 
$manager->persist($marie); 
$epoux_se = new Epoux_se("Aurel", ["Jean-Christophe", "Marc"], "M", "Saint-Malo", "05/08/1722", 22); 
$manager->persist($epoux_se); 
$manager->flush();
```

How to do ? Thank you !

Comment: can you show how do you create fixtures?

Comment: $marie = new Individu("Duhamel", ["Ophelia", "Carmène"], "F");                             
        $manager->persist($marie);                                                                                                        
        $epoux_se = new Epoux_se("Aurel", ["Jean-Christophe", "Marc"], "M", "Saint-Malo", "05/08/1722", 22);
        $manager->persist($epoux_se);                                                                                    
        $manager->flush();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution ! It's necessary to add the following annotation above Individual Entity

> - @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")

```
/**
* Individu
*
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
*
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\IndividuRepository")
*/
class Individu
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the visibility of parent class attributes to protected. And then update your database scheme.

Comment: Not working, I've drop my database and update then import DataFixtures but I've the same problem. I try with public and protected for each attribute into entity Individual and Husband

Comment: Din't realized that the field causing the problem is a relation field. I have some entities also defined extending from base ones  and I had to override the atrributes that are relations in the child class. For standard "plain" attributes inheritance works but for relationships it seems that it doesn't.